# Error unnesting list-columns in R even all have equal lengths

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm getting this error "Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements." but I can't figure out why as my list columns have equal lengths.
Here is an example:

```
> df <- tibble(x = c("a", "b", "c"), y = list(a = 1:3, b = 4:6, c = 7:9), z = list(as.character(1:3)))
> df
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  x     y         z        
  <chr> <list>    <list>   
1 a     <int [3]> <chr [3]>
2 b     <int [3]> <chr [3]>
3 c     <int [3]> <chr [3]>

> unnest(df)
Error: All nested columns must have the same number of elements.
```

**EDIT**: unnest(slice(df,1:n())) works.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't like your list to be named, I think it qualifies as a bug. This works: `df %>% mutate_at("y",unname) %>% unnest`

Comment: this is strange because the `.id` parameter exists specifically to handle named lists. I can reproduce your issue but I can't upgrade to latest version, so if you don't have the latest one I'd suggest to upgrade and see if it persists.